# Features 'reveal pointer' does not work, whereas previously functioning properly

Tags: mouse, touchpad

Features 'reveal pointer' does not work, whereas previously functioning properly. #loki

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug tracked at https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-mouse-touchpad/+bug/1627121.

In green near the top of the page is "Does this bug affect you?" Click that and register yourself for notifications from the developers.